# Is there a way to navigate back after an inter-page jump in a PDF reader?

Tags: pdf

Say I am reading a paper with a PDF reader on a tablet and I get to

> ... the second inequality follows from Lemma 3.2 ...

and I click on the text "Lemma 3.2" to jump to Lemma 3.2. Now that I reminded myself of what Lemma 3.2 was, I need to go back to the page I was reading before the jump.

In case of Adobe Reader which I am using on my phone, the physical back button (which I believe corresponds to the system back button) simply gets me to the recent files list.

Is there a way to navigate back after an inter-page jump in a PDF reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ezPDF Reader ([free trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader.trial), [pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader)) supports this.

Assuming you have a table of contents (TOC), clicking on a chapter link will take you to a page far from the TOC. If you click on the button with "a page and left arrow" icon (encircled below), it will take you back to the TOC.

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 0):

From the (now deleted) [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54350/any-pdf-reader-with-the-go-back-feature?rq=1#comment72954_54350),

> I found that Adobe Reader on Android actually has "go back" feature; after I jump to Lemma 3.2, the reader displays a new button which is for "go back". I guess I didn't try jump before because I was not expecting such a button to be created on the fly like that.